# Using Hibernate with a map for the attributes of a table

Tags: hibernate

So I have some code that represents a songs metadata, instead of having getters and setters for each field I put the values in map, each field is a String, and I have a seperate enum for each field. This makes the the code alot simpler

Im now looking to hibernatise this code, am Im going to lose this simplicity and have to have getters and setters for each field

```
public class Song
{

    protected final EnumMap<SongFieldKey,SongField> fields = new EnumMap<SongFieldKey,SongField>(SongFieldKey.class);


    public Song()
    {

    }


    /**
     * Return table cell datatype
     */
    public final SongField getField(SongFieldKey field)
    {
        return fields.get(field);
    }


    ................
}

public enum SongFieldKey
{
    ALBUM,
    ALBUM_ARTIST,
    ALBUM_ARTIST_SORT,
    ALBUM_SORT,
    AMAZON_ID,
    ARRANGER,
    ARTIST,
    ....
}
```

Comment: do you have a table to store all the entries in the **SongFieldKey**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Hibernate allows you to map `Map`s, `Entity Map`a and `Collections` of simple datatypes and classes.

You would do this like that (for a `Map<String, String>`):

```
<map name="songFields">
  <key column="id"/>
  <index column="name" type="string"/>
  <element column="songField" type="string"/>
</map>
```

With such a entry in your `hbm.xml`, all the values you would put in the map would be stored in the newly created table called `songFields`.

So, in the worst case your example could work if you replaced the enum with a set of static `String` fields (which I assume you don't want to do, do you? :-))

When you try to replace the `string` with an `Enum` type, the mapping wont work out of the box. What you need to do is to somehow map your `Enum` class to `varchar` field in the DB.

This is the way how you can do it.

First, in your `*.hbm.xml` file define a new type of `org.hibernate.type.EnumType` class with your `SongFieldKey` as a `enumClass` parameter and `12` as a `type` parameter. (The magic `12` is defined in `java.sql.Type` as `VARCHAR`.)

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
    <typedef name="songFieldKey" class="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">org.nowaq.hql.enums.SongFieldKey</param>
        <param name="type">12</param>
    </typedef>

    ...
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

When you have this in place, you can go ahead an write your `<map ...` replacing the `string` with `songFieldKey` like this:

```
<map name="songFields">
  <key column="id"/>
  <index column="fieldId" type="songFieldKey"/>
  <element column="field" type="string"/>
</map>
```

This should solve your "no getters and setters" problem. (I assumed no usage of `SongField` type for simplicity in the `<element>` tag so my map looked like this in code: `private EnumMap<SongFieldKey, String> fields;`.)

Anyway, make sure to understand the efficiency of this solution and take a look at these:

- http://blog.javachap.com/index.php/enumeration-mapping-in-hibernate/
- http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingAnEnumWithAVARCHARColumn
- http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html

Hope this helps. Worked with Hibernate 3.4 and MySQL5 db.